# Redirect console output to a file during java method execution from inside groovy script

Tags: groovy

How to redirect the console output to a file from inside a groovy script ?
I need to call a main method:

```
xsdgenerator = Class.forName("org.wiztools.xsdgen.XsdGenMain", true, loader).newInstance()
xsdgenerator.main(args)
```

This main method outputs to console. Can i redirect the console output to any file from groovy script.Because i need to do a few corrections in the output and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
PrintStream archived = System.out
try {
    new File( 'output.log' ).withOutputStream { os ->
        System.out = new PrintStream( os )
        xsdgenerator = Class.forName("org.wiztools.xsdgen.XsdGenMain", true, loader).newInstance()
        xsdgenerator.main(args)
    }
}
finally {
    System.out = archived
}
```